# c programming: stopping endless loops

Tags: c, validation

I have been trying to get my head around validating the code, a.k.a stopping the program from breaking and entering the endless loops but I find it quite difficult.

So far I have come across multiple points in the program where the user can break it by entering the wrong input for example with the main menu if the user enters a letter or symbol instead of a number the program enters the endless loop, so a basic guide on validating would be helpful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct packet{
    int source;
    int destination;
    int type;
    int port;
    char data[50];
};

void main ()
{

struct packet s[50]; //Array for structure input
int choice;
int customerCount = 0, ii = 0;

 while (customerCount <= 50){
                 printf("What would you like to do?\n");

                 printf("\t1) Add a packet.\n");
                 printf("\t2) s all packets.\n");
                 printf("\t3) Save packets.\n");
                 printf("\t4) Clear all packets.\n");
                 printf("\t5) Quit the programme.\n");
                 scanf("%i", &choice);

    switch (choice)
                    {
                        case 1: printf("\n****Adding a packet*****\n");
                                printf("Where is the packet from?\n");
                                scanf("%i", &s[customerCount].source);
                                printf("Where is the packet going?\n");
                                scanf("%i", &s[customerCount].destination);
                                printf("What type is the packet?\n");
                                scanf("%i", &s[customerCount].type);
                                printf("What is the packet's port?\n");
                                scanf("%i", &s[customerCount].port);
                                printf("Enter up to 50 characters of data.\n");
                                scanf("%s", s[customerCount].data);
                                customerCount++;
                                break;

                        case 2: printf("\nDisplaying Infomation\n");
                                for(ii = 0; ii < customerCount; ii++) {
                                printf("\nSource: %d", s[ii].source);
                                printf("\nDestination: %d", s[ii].destination );
                                printf("\nType : %d", s[ii].type);
                                printf("\nPort : %d", s[ii].port);
                                printf("\nData: %s\n---\n", s[ii].data);
                                 }
                        break;


                        case 3: break;

                        case 4: break;

                        case 5: break;

                        default: printf("\nThis is not a valid choice, please choose again\n\n");
                                 break;
                    }
                    }
 }
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: `scanf` returns the number of arguments successfully converted.  You must check that it's 1 for all the numeric conversions and if not loop to prompt and scan again until it is.  This logic can be placed in a separate function so it need not be repeated.

Comment: On the 2nd paragraph i asked about how would i fix the issue with the endless loop when I enter a letter

Comment: The code you've given doesn't go into an endless loop if given a letter.

Comment: it does on the main menu which is the first action given

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` returns the number of arguments it successfully scanned.

Checking for proper input and rejecting bad input can be as simple as:

```
printf("Where is the packet from?\n");
while(scanf("%i", &s[customerCount].source) != 1)
{
    while(getchar() != '\n')
        continue;
}
```

This is not very robust, however, and something like validating user input should be very robust.  Assume the user will always enter wrong input... it's sad but true.